# Bus error when dereferencing the same address

Tags: c

I'm trying the `squeeze` program from K&R. However, I keep getting a bus error. The code below directly triggers the problem. Shouldn't this be portable?

```
int main() {
    char* str = "foo";
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; str[i]; ++i)
        str[j] = '.';
}
```

The function from the book:

```
void squeeze(char s[], int c)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (s[i] != c)
            s[j++] = s[i];
    s[j] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: What hardware are you using?

Comment: Probably a dupe of this: [**Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a "char *s" initialized with a string literal, but not "char s\[\]"?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-char-s-initialized-with-a)

Answer (score 0):

`str` points to a string constant.  Such constants are read only, so attempting to modify them triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in your particular case manifests in the program crashing.

Instead, declare `str` as an array, which can be modified:

```
char str[] = "foo";
```

Comment: I never understood this, it doesn't seem to be a limitation of the hardware but of C itself. Is there a reason why there's a difference? Does the compiler just turn this into `push 0x666F6F00` (or the equivalent in whatever assembly is being used?)

Comment: This worked! Does that mean that their function teaches undefined behaviour?

Comment: @puppydrum64 Compilers will typically place string literals in regions of memory marked read-only.

Comment: Do they have to, or is this a design choice?

Comment: @puppydrum64: Re “Is there a reason why there's a difference?”: The C standard specifies that a string literal causes the creation of an array of characters for which the behavior of attempting to modify them is not defined. The array has type “array of `char`” for historical reasons; if `const` had been in the language when string literals were specified, the array would be “array of `const char`”. In contrast, `char str[] = "foo";` creates an array for which the behavior of attempting to modify the elements is specified.

Comment: @L.S.Roth The squeeze example from K&R didn't mention how the string was allocated on the caller side. It assumes read/write memory.

Comment: @puppydrum64 On microcontroller systems, string literals are allocated in non-volatile, read-only flash memory. Which can't be written to. Which is a good thing since RAM is more valuable than flash and you don't want to download constants to RAM just for the heck of it.